# Не получается научить телеграм-бот передавать картинки ( python)

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

Пишу простенький чат-бот на python. При попытке вывести картинку пользователю командой

```
send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa79jq2IAAeKbxZlKZzjOr7fSwOE6gq8AAknEMRuiG2BJ8GjPO87SHcEBAAMCAAN5AAMsBA')
```

командная строка винды выдаёт ошибку: "name 'send_photo_file_unique_id' is not defined". Библиотека telebot, картинка заранее загружена на сервер телеграма. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка?

В гугле не могу найти(

Полный код вот:

```
from telebot import types
import telebot;
bot = telebot.TeleBot('--token--')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def get_text_messages(message):

    if message.text == '/start':

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text1')
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text2')

    elif message.text == 'Вперёд!':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text3')

    elif message.text == '11010000 10100001 00100000 11010000':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text4')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa8Njq2J-qlhC2gNkpPTr_-JSiryNuQACS8QxG6IbYEk2KUXAsZB7wQEAAwIAA3kAAywE')

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text5') 
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text6')

    elif message.text == '10011101 11010000 10111110 11010000':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text7')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa8Fjq2Iruv7QcezebLv1hazQFe2bewACSsQxG6IbYEluiPh7_0BTxwEAAwIAA3gAAywE')

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text8')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa79jq2IAAeKbxZlKZzjOr7fSwOE6gq8AAknEMRuiG2BJ8GjPO87SHcEBAAMCAAN5AAMsBA')

    elif message.text == '10110010 11010001 10001011 11010000':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text9')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa7tjq2HlZALBxThydSWH7uBIaHKkZgACSMQxG6IbYEkBau7icUisCQEAAwIAA3kAAywE')

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text10')

    elif message.text == 'text':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text11')

    elif message.text == '10111100 00100000 11010000 10010011':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text12')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa7ljq2GwJWAde2NVX1DDkG8mExQtXwACRsQxG6IbYEncO0N_-Ka98gEAAwIAA3kAAywE')

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text13')

    elif message.text == '11010000 10111110 11010000 10110100':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text14')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa7djq2GNM2kcHbYU1pUD6NmfgOcAATkAAkXEMRuiG2BJyAJk43SIOJkBAAMCAAN4AAMsBA')

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text15')

    elif message.text == '11010000 10111110 11010000 10111100':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text16')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa7Vjq2DrxPHHRrIozb-Vl5KP59d_RAACQ8QxG6IbYElJgYHJ36ncWAEAAwIAA3kAAywE')

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text17')

    elif message.text == 'С Новым Годом':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'text18')
        send_photo_file_id(chat_id, 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAETa69jq1-JNGlag3Nf15ioyDL7NwGhKgACPsQxG6IbYEkmuJz4qDMsmwEAAwIAA3kAAywE')
        send_audio_file_id(chat_id, 'CQACAgIAAxkBAAETa8Vjq2KvggrY-g4yA0vNSujVSg5NTAACSiUAAqIbYEnL2WgGXSENmiwE')

    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'error)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полный код. Так сложно судит ьв чем именно проблемы. Как вариант - вы забыли подключить какой-то из модулей.

Comment: Добавила в описание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно открыть фото и записать его в переменную.

```
photo1=open(r'Путь/photo1.jpg', 'rb')
```

После, фото оправляется командой:

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

Comment: Спасибо! 

А как можно сделать так, чтобы фото отправлялось не из компьютера пользователя, а из телеграма? Я загрузила все фотки на сервер телеграма, у меня есть их id-шники, их надо указать в коде. Попробовала вставить их в примере, который вы привели - ругается, что нет такого файла или директории, что неудивительно

Comment: Оо, всё, разобралась. Спасибо огромное, ваш ответ помог! Потребовалось ещё модуль подключить, но в итоге всё - ура! - работает!!!))))

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь вам)